# ListViewItem loses background color when repainted and the cursor is over the item

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a listview control obviously with numerous listviewitems, whenever the control is repainted the item which the mouse is "over" at the time loses it's background colour (ie. it's white).

Once the item is painted again and the cursor is not over it the correct background colour is restored.

Does anyone know why this happens and how it can be stopped?

Any help would be appreciated

To expand on this and hopefully give a little more context....

It's happening on Windows 7, .NET 3.5 (although it was also happening when the project was targetted at 4.0 too). The theme on my dev computer is Viao Theme 5, however it also happens on another of my machines which has the default Windows 7 theme.

The listview is instantiated like this...

```
        this.PlaylistTrackList.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
        this.PlaylistTrackList.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.PlaylistTrackList.FullRowSelect = true;
        this.PlaylistTrackList.HeaderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderStyle.Nonclickable;
        this.PlaylistTrackList.LabelWrap = false;
        this.PlaylistTrackList.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 4);
        this.PlaylistTrackList.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
        this.PlaylistTrackList.MultiSelect = false;
        this.PlaylistTrackList.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        this.PlaylistTrackList.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
```

Let's say there are 5 list view items, A,B,C,D, and E. If the background color property of items BC and D is red, nothing is selected and nothing is going to be selected. When the list view control is redrawn for whatever reason and the cursor happens to be over any of items BC or D then the item is drawn with a white background color not red as it should be. However once the mouse is not over the item again and its redrawn is returns to red.

How can I stop it always drawing the item that the cursor is over with a white background regardless of the "real" background color property?

Comment: could you post some code that show us your current 'paint' method? i think you're talking of a normal behaviour. the background colour after selecting turns to 'blue'? maybe possible that you have activated 'hoverselection'. items will be automatically selected if you move the mouse over them.

Comment: Hi varg, I don't have a custom paint method and it's not related to selecting an item. I'm simply setting the background color property of various items based on a status. However when the control is re-drawn the background color of items when the mouse is "over" them are drawn as white not the correct background color. OwnerDraw is false and so is HotTracking and Hover selection.

Comment: This question requires more details.  At least Windows version, .NET version, active Windows theme and the ListView initialization.  Preferably a copy/paste from the Designer.cs code.

Comment: Hi Hans, question updated with the extra details

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the ListView control as follows:

```
    listView1.BackColor = Color.Black;
    listView1.ForeColor = Color.White;
    listView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    listView1.View = View.Details;
    listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
```

For more details check the following link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw.aspx

Comment: Hi, the ListView is initialized like that, do I really need to fully implement my own drawing to get round this behaviour?